# Session time runs out even if there is time in SESSID

Tags: php, session

I have a social website. People use login with username and password. I am creating a session when they log in but some time later session time ends and they have to log back in again. I used the code below to make this time longer but still sometime later session time runs out. I checked SESSID with cromes cookie viewer and saw session still has time but in the browser it does not see that time. I hope i explained my problem well. Here is the code to create the session on login:

```
 $lifetime=3600*24*7;
 session_start();
 setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

Comment: you don't need to set a session cookie... PHP does this for you. Also the cookie expiry has nothing to do with session expiry, see `session.gc_maxlifetime` in php ini.

Comment: I put this code but again time is running out. ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
session_start();

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at: `session.gc_maxlifetime` in your configuration. This needs to have a high enough value, to keep the session alive. Also if you are using Memcache or some other caching for your sessions, the TTL there needs to be set, too.